# I have a connecting flight at CDG, do I need a visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, cdg

I am landing at terminal 1 of CDG airport from NY and need to catch a connecting flight at terminal 2E at CDG airport. Will I be required to get a visa to make this transfer?

Comment: Are both your flights on a single ticket (i.e., one **P**assenger **N**ame **R**ecord? Or do you have two separate tickets, each on a different airline? Will you have checked luggage?

Comment: You need to mention your citizenship, where is your onward flight to, is your US visa valid? An answer to these questions is required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: @ThomasCruise, as OP did tag the question Indian Citizen, I am pretty much sure that is their nationality.

Comment: FYI, T1 is closed until EoY

Answer (score 4):

The above answer from @jcaron lays down the documentation requirements

Provided you can do air-side transit, you can take the Blue shuttle from T1 (airside) directly to T2E gates L (16 min. transit time), K (21-23 min. transit time) and M (transfer to the Purple shuttle at 2E-L (Add 7' + eventual wait for the shuttle))

[image]

---

**NOTE: This was the answer while T1 was shutdown due to COVID**

There are no air-side Non Schengen-Non Schengen (i.e. not passing through immigration) transfer facilities from/to CDG's Terminal 1 (and also T3) (only between 2E-F-G) (at least not until 2040). Your luggage may be transferred depending if you're on a single ticket.

This means you **will** need to pass passport control and hold a Schengen **short-stay C**-Visa and **NOT** an Airport Transit Visa (like is stated in @hojusaram answer, but this only applied to airside transfers, which a transit to/from T1/T3 isn't)

Once through passport control, and on the arrival floor, follow the signs, take the elevators down to the basement and take the rail shuttle CDGVAL [image] to Terminal 2 station

Travel time : 8 minutes

Once arrived at the Terminal 2 station, follow the signs, walk a bit through to T2E, pass security, passport control and board as usual

Comment: Note that before T1 shut down, there was an airside shuttle between T1 and T2A (green shuttle): https://web.archive.org/web/20190616100202/https://www.parisaeroport.fr/passagers/acces/paris-charles-de-gaulle/navettes-inter-terminaux I would expect it to be reinstated when T1 re-opens

Comment: Yeah, didn't think about that one

Comment: Are you sure there is no 'transfer without a Schengen visa' in CDG at this time? Your answer is quite a contrast with the other answers.

Comment: @Willeke This answer only applies to Terminal 1 and 3 while they are closed, not bewtween 2E/2F/2G where there is airside facilities, we don't know how it will pan out when both reopen, the old shuttle scheme, as provided by jcaron, will very likely be reintroduced

Comment: @jcaron Quite surprised it didn't get reintroduced like that (the green one has been scrapped) and that for once they made it more convenient to transit at CDG

Answer (score 3):

- If your flights are on **separate tickets**: you will need a **full type C Schengen visa**.
- If your flights are on the **same ticket and you can do airside transit**:

  - If you have a **valid visa or permanent resident card from the US**, an EU country, Canada or Japan (and a few others): **no visa required**.
  - **Otherwise**: an **airport transit visa (ATV) is required**.

At this time, there is no possibility to do airside transit between T1 and T2, but that's probably just because T1 is closed. I would expect an airside shuttle between T1 and T2 to resume once T1 reopens, though the exact route may be complex (before it shut down, you had to take one shuttle from T1 to T2A and then another shuttle to T2E).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

As per https://wwws.airfrance.in/information/meilleures-offres/travelrestrictions

> As of April 27, 2021, The French authorities have implemented new travel requirements. Passengers holding  Indian passports must be in possession of a valid  Airport Transit Visa (ATV) to transit via France for final destination outside the Schengen Area.

Comment: Note that this applies only if the traveler can stay airside. Also there is an exception for holders of a valid visa. But if OP needs to go through passport control (which they would if they indeed transit from T1 to T2, or if they have to do check-in for their next flight), they need a full visa, not an ATV.